Csharp xunit Test case failing for Amazons3 Class methods(GetPreSignedURL,PutObjectAsync,ListObjectsV2Async)
I have Amazons3 class with its methods (GetPreSignedURL,PutObjectAsync,ListObjectsV2Async) . I am trying to Mock them using Moq in C# Xunit . But it is failing in the calling method.
AmazonS3 Class Code
public class AmazonServiceService : IAmazonService
{
    private IAmazonS3 _client = null;
   
    
    public AmazonServiceService()
    {

    }

    public void CreateAmazonS3Client(ObjectStorageConfiguration config)
    {
        _client = new AmazonS3Client(config.AccessKeyId, config.Secret, new AmazonS3Config
        {
            ServiceURL = config.ServerUrl
        });
    }

    public  string GetPreSignedUrl(string? fileName, string? bucketName)
    {
        var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = fileName,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
        };

        // Get path for request
        return _client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
    }

    public string CreateDirectoryInS3Bucket(string? bucketName, string? directoryPath)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the directory object 
            PutObjectRequest request = new()
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = directoryPath,
                ContentBody = "" // Empty content body for a directory 
            };
            var directoryCreated= _client.PutObjectAsync(request).Result;
            return directoryPath??  "";
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception ex)
        {

            if (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            throw;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    
    public async Task<bool> FileExist(string? filename, string? bucket)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new ListObjectsV2Request
            {
                BucketName = bucket,
                Prefix = filename,
            };

            var response = await _client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);
            return response.S3Objects.Any();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { 
        return false;
        }
    }
}

What I have tried, failing in mock setup step with error "Non-overridable members (here: AmazonS3Client.GetPreSignedURL) may not be used in setup"
private ObjectStorageService CreateService()
 {
     return new ObjectStorageService();
 }

 The below test case is getting passed after the change to IAmazonS3
`[Fact]
public void CreateAmazonS3Client_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior()
{
    //Arrange
    ObjectStorageConfiguration config = new ObjectStorageConfiguration
    {
        AccessKeyId = "AccessKey",
        Secret = "Secret",
        ServerUrl = "http://testserver.com/"
    };
    // Act
    var mockS3Client = new Mock<IAmazonS3>();
    var expectedUrl = "https://testserver.com/bucketName/fileName?AWSAccessKeyId=AccessKey&Expires=1731254511&Signature=XS%2B19Ihey4u8jfLAOeQcv3ojrUw%3D";

    var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
    {
        BucketName = "bucketName",
        Key = "fileName",
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
    };
   
    mockS3Client
        .Setup(client => client.GetPreSignedURL(request))
        .Returns(expectedUrl);

    var objService = new ObjectStorageService(); // Replace with your actual service class
    objService.CreateAmazonS3Client(config);
    // Act
    var result = objService.GetPreSignedUrl("fileName", "bucketName");

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(expectedUrl, result);
    mockS3Client.Verify(client => client.GetPreSignedURL(request), Times.Once);



    // Assert
    Assert.True(false);
    this.mockRepository.VerifyAll();
}`


Non-overridable members (here: AmazonS3Client.GetPreSignedURL) may not be used in setup What about that error is unclear to you?

var mockS3Client = new Mock<AmazonS3Client>(); Change this to var mockS3Client = new Mock<IAmazonS3Client>();

The below test case is getting passed after the change to IAmazonS3
